# ssh2 execution lifetime on the remote side

Tags: php, bash, unix, ssh

I am trying to run a bash script using php-ssh2. The script must run forever in the remote machine (the only way to stop it must be with `pkill`). The problem is that somehow the connection is closed and the bash script is killed.

Nohup, disown and screen... I tried everything and nothing really changed, it simply doesn't keep that script alive.

What can I do?

(I know that this is a security hole (HUGE) but this is just experimental, the main idea is using an HTML button, run a bash script in the server computer, using apache2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a frequent cron job (every minute?) that first checks some kind of a flag (e.g. existence of certain file) before running a job.

In the PHP code, only raise the flag (create the file).

Comment: I am kind of new with PHP. How can I raise the flag (create the file)? And how can I use cron here?

Comment: Sorry, but that makes the scope of this question pretty wide. What is agaisnt this site policy. I believe I've outlined basic concept. Do your research on individual steps, or ask separate questions for details (though all of them are likely answered already).

Answer (score 0):

Does the script generate output? If not, check out the keep alive option of ssh.

Comment: how can I check that option of ssh for php?

Comment: It's an option of a normal ssh client. Not sure if the php-ssh2 thing has this. If not, you could let your script generate some output while running (if it's not already doing that) to achieve the same effect.